# crossfilter.js: How to manage two different sets of filter configurations

Tags: javascript, data-analysis, crossfilter

I want to show a list of entities, filtered based on certain metadata, and once an entity selected, I want to get all data for that entity to show details over time. These are two different 'queries' to crossfilter, and the question is, do I need two different Crossfilter instances for that?

Details:

I have a dataset containing many rows of metadata per entities, over time, e.g.

```
[{'id': 0, 'time': 0, 'p1': 1, 'p2':345, 'value': 0},
 {'id': 0, 'time': 1, 'p1': 2, 'p2':789, 'value': 1},
 {'id': 1, 'time': 0, 'p1': 3, 'p2':123, 'value': 2},...]
```

First, I want to get all rows which fulfill certain criteria, let's say `.time==1` and `.p1>2`. These selections are made such that I get a list of *unique ids*.

Now I show all the entities to which those `id`s belong. If a user selects one of those, I want to get something different from my dataset: All rows where `.id=[selected id]`.

I know I can reset the filters on all dimensions, but I'd also like to keep the previous settings active because a user might change the filters leading to the first selection after I've done the second selection.

So what I really want are two crossfilter instances probably. However, I am loading a *lot* of data and ideally I wouldn't want to keep the data around in two different crossfilter instances.

I guess my question is: Does crossfilter duplicate the data when I load it into a Crossfilter instance? And if it does, is there a way to maintain two different filtering states of it without having to duplicate the whole instances?